# mod_rewrite spins off additional subrequest for rewrites using PATH_INFO

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Suppose I want to route all requests starting with `/test/` to a single PHP file `info.php`. I can do this by passing the original `%{REQUEST_URI}` as:

1. A query string parameter, as in

   ```
   info.php?request_uri=/test/some/path
   ```

   **or,**
2. `PATH_INFO`—the path string immediately following the `info.php`, as in

   ```
   info.php/test/some/path
   ```

There are other ways too (e.g. environment variable), but my question is regarding strange behavior when using `PATH_INFO`.

The problem is that according to the rewrite log, the `PATH_INFO` method generates one more subrequest than the query string method.

Can someone explain why this is?

## Details

`DOCUMENT_ROOT` is at `/var/www`. First line of `httpd -V` is:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
```

#### PATH_INFO

The contents of `/var/www/test/.htaccess` file are as follows:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
DirectorySlash off
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# Only perform the rewrite for first round of mod_rewrite processing.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
# Pass current path as PATH_INFO to PHP script.
RewriteRule ^ info.php%{REQUEST_URI}
```

A request for `/test/some/path` yields the following rewritelog output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b5d888/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] add path info postfix: /var/www/test/some -> /var/www/test/some/path
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b5d888/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/some/path -> some/path
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b5d888/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'some/path'
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b5d888/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/test/] RewriteCond: input='' pattern='=' => matched
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b5d888/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/test/] rewrite 'some/path' -> 'info.php/test/some/path'
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b5d888/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] add per-dir prefix: info.php/test/some/path -> /var/www/test/info.php/test/some/path
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b5d888/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/test/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/test/info.php/test/some/path -> /test/info.php/test/some/path
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b5d888/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/test/] internal redirect with /test/info.php/test/some/path [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b54fd0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] add path info postfix: /var/www/test/info.php -> /var/www/test/info.php/test/some/path
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b54fd0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/info.php/test/some/path -> info.php/test/some/path
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b54fd0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'info.php/test/some/path'
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b54fd0/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir /var/www/test/] RewriteCond: input='200' pattern='=' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b54fd0/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/test/] pass through /var/www/test/info.php

(The subrequest begins here)

127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b4d818/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] add path info postfix: /var/www/test/some -> /var/www/test/some/path
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b4d818/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/some/path -> some/path
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b4d818/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'some/path'
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b4d818/subreq] (4) [perdir /var/www/test/] RewriteCond: input='200' pattern='=' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:46:22 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b4d818/subreq] (1) [perdir /var/www/test/] pass through /var/www/test/some
```

#### Query string

The last line of `/var/www/test/.htaccess` is changed to:

```
RewriteRule ^ info.php?request_uri=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

A request for `/test/some/path` yields the following rewritelog output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:49:07 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b56858/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] add path info postfix: /var/www/test/some -> /var/www/test/some/path
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:49:07 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b56858/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/some/path -> some/path
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:49:07 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b56858/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'some/path'
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:49:07 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b56858/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/test/] RewriteCond: input='' pattern='=' => matched
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:49:07 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b56858/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/test/] rewrite 'some/path' -> 'info.php?request_uri=/test/some/path'
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:49:07 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b56858/initial] (3) split uri=info.php?request_uri=/test/some/path -> uri=info.php, args=request_uri=/test/some/path
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:49:07 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b56858/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] add per-dir prefix: info.php -> /var/www/test/info.php
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:49:07 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b56858/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/test/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/test/info.php -> /test/info.php
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:49:07 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b56858/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/test/] internal redirect with /test/info.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:49:07 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b54fe0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/info.php -> info.php
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:49:07 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b54fe0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'info.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:49:07 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b54fe0/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir /var/www/test/] RewriteCond: input='200' pattern='=' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2015:19:49:07 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f5a056a9880][rid#7f5a05b54fe0/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/test/] pass through /var/www/test/info.php
```

As you can see, no subrequest appears in this rewritelog output.